# Proper Syntax for Extension Method Query

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I am trying to do something similar to my previous post, except I am using extension methods instead of LINQ. I get an error telling me that && cannot be used, so how would I search within a table using two strings entered by the user?

```
var query = (App.DBConnection.Table<Notes>().Where(
                    c => c.Note.Contains(textBox1.Text) && c => c.Note.Contains(textBox2.Text))).Single();
TextBox_Results.Text = query.Note;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the second [lambda](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx) operator `c =>`

```
var query = App.DBConnection.Table<Notes>()
    .Where(c => c.Note.Contains(textBox1.Text) 
             && c.Note.Contains(textBox2.Text)))
    .Single();
```

Apart from that, i would use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `Single`. The latter throws an `InvalidOperationException` if there are no elements or if there are more than one. The former just returns `null` if no item matches the predicate in the `Where`.

Comment: If a single result is expected, then I think `Single()` makes the most sense, because it fails in a clear way when something unexpected happens.

Comment: @svick: A `String.Contains` on two different substrings is nothing where i expect a single result.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea how I would print that out to a TextBox? `TextBox_Results.Text = query.Note;` throws an error that states, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: @cdalto: Yes, as i've mentioned above `FirstOrDefault`(or `SingleOrDefault`) returns `null` if no item was found. So either check if it's null previously or use `TextBox_Results.Text = query.Note ?? "";`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare the `c` variable again

```
Where(c => c.Note.Contains(textBox1.Text) && c => c.Note.Contains(textBox2.Text)))
```

should be

```
Where(c => c.Note.Contains(textBox1.Text) && c.Note.Contains(textBox2.Text)))
```